# Flex swf file taking time to load at client side

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

In my project we have swf file that is 4 mb in size. When we open the application in browser it is taking 3-5 seconds to load the swf file at client side. Is there any way to compress the swf file and send so that it will take less time? Or is there any other options to minimise the load time?

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: is it the main swf file or a module that gets loaded on runtime?

Comment: It's one module swf file.

Answer (score 0):

By default swf files are already compressed when compiled. Try zipping an swf file for example it will hardly change in size.

If you find a compression method to do decrease the size of the swf and this compression method is supported by flash, you can compress the swf file for download and decompress it at runtime and then load it.

Comment: I tried using GZIP compression but it doesn't compress swf file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read ["Reducing SWF file sizes"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf67110-7ff4.html)

   - Use the bytecode optimizer
   - Disable debugging
   - Use strict mode
   - Avoid initializing unused classes
   - Externalize assets
   - Use character ranges for embedded fonts
2. Read ["Reducing module size"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d1f.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d15)

   - Change the application that a module is optimized for in Flash Builder
   - Create and use a linker report with the command-line compiler
3. Modularize your module
4. Compress your assets (higher jpg compression, lower color depth, etc)